# How to retrieve metrics from spring-boot micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I was experimenting with micrometer using below code. How do i configure rate aggregation and get rate-aggregated data from a given counter within the application. By rate aggregated i mean data for previous publishing interval ?

```
final MeterRegistry myRegistry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
final Random random = new Random();
for (iteration = 0; iteration < 1000; iteration++)
{
    final int randomNum = random.nextInt(10);
    final Counter myCounter = myRegistry.counter("myTestCounter", "random", Integer.toString(randomNum));
    myCounter.increment();
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
System.out.println("measure = [" + myRegistry.counter("myTestCounter", "random", "0").measure());
System.out.println("count = [" + myRegistry.counter("myTestCounter", "random", "0").count());
```

Note: I dont want to publish metrics to any monitoring system. I would like to track number of requests given tags per interval (e.g., successful/failure requests   for a given interval) in application itself and use it for resilience purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment from the author of the project, Micrometer intends to export metrics to an external product-ready monitoring system like Prometheus, so your approach is kind of unusual.

Micrometer supports rate-aggregation for monitoring systems which don't support rate-aggregation like InfluxDB and its support comes from `StepMeterRegistry`. But `SimpleMeterRegistry` is not one of its subclasses, so you need to create your own one if you want to stick to the approach.

UPDATED:

I created [a sample for a custom `StepMeterRegistry`](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer/blob/master/src/test/java/learningtest/io/micrometer/core/instrument/step/StepMeterRegistryTests.java).

Comment: Thanks @johhny-lim. Off topic - Do you know if there is a library that caters to my requirements ?

Comment: @joshu Creating your own `StepMeterRegistry` isn't difficult. I updated my answer to add a sample for it.

Comment: I am searching for the same. It isn't unusual. We export statistics for an extern metering system but also want to show some simple set of values on a small status page without an http request to the exported endpoints. For me the question is does make sense.